# Negative number to string array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Problem: Write a function that takes an array of numbers and replaces any number that's negative to a string called 'Dojo'. For example if array = [-1,-3,2] should return ['Dojo', 'Dojo', 2]

Am I not calling the array correctly?

My code:

```
function numToStr(arr) {
    //your code here 
    var str = 'Dojo';
    var newarr=arr[i];
    for(var i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]<0){
            arr[i]=str;
        }
        else{
            newarr=arr[i];
        }
    }
    return newarr; 
}
```

Comment: Please mention which programming language this is.

Comment: Hi Juhana, sorry. It's javascript.

Comment: the problem was you were setting newarr to arr[i] before the variable i existed, and then were returning the bad newarr variable if the number was negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the problem statement that you should just get rid of the `newarr` variable (along with the `else` part of the `if` statement) and `return arr;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method I know is [.map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
Also you can use string '-5' as an array element, it will also be replaced by 'Dojo' as a negative integer value.

```js
a=[-1,-3,2,'-5'].map(function(x){return ~~x < 0 ? 'Dojo' : x ;})
alert(a);
```